# iTunes thinks there is a podcast on my ipod when there isn't

Tags: itunes, podcasts, ipod-nano

Every day I listen to podcasts. When I'm done with them, I plug the iPod into the computer and uncheck the ones I no longer want, and then hit "sync" again. iTunes thinks that there is a podcast on my iPod... but there isn't, and nor should there be. Not a huge deal, but very annoying. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reset my iPod to factory settings. That fixed it!

Comment: I wish I knew why it worked. All I know is that now it shows the correct number of podcasts that are on the iPod. If anybody could offer an explanation as to why it worked, that would be appreciated... because I don't even know why this happened to begin with!